# does datetime.now returns a datetime in different format on win7 vs win10?

Tags: .net, winforms, date, datetime

I have a visual basic program(Windows forms) that runs on windows 7, there are parts of the program that uses the datetime.now property to insert the date into the SQL database. Today, after copying the same program onto a windows 10 PC, i realised the date format of the date inserted into the (same SQL db)  is different. e.g 06-09-2017(from prog on win7) and 09-06-2018(from prog on win10)
date on taskbar of win7 pc shows: 6/9/2017  win10:9/6/2017

DateTime.now is defined on msdn as:
Gets a DateTime object that is set to the current date and time on this computer, expressed as the local time.

Comment: Avoid converting it into a string at any time and you avoid any formatting issues. `DateTime` internally is just a count of 100ns intervals since midnight 01/01/0001. ADO.Net knows how to translate a .NET `DateTime` into a SQL Server `datetime`, which again doesn't *have* a format, it's just a count.

Comment: @Icepickle - no, conversions to *strings* of `DateTime` will be based on regional settings (assuming no explicit attempt to control formatting). The `DateTime` itself is unaffected.

Comment: "local time" means local time ZONE (or rather offset from UTC)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The windows version doesnt affect the date time format however you need to check the DateTime format in your Windows Region Settings > Change DateTime Format.